# Longtext in Mysql not working in live server...Showing Forbidden Error

Tags: mysql, longtext

in my project I have one text field for project details(longtext). In localhost it is working fine, but in live server when I am trying to add the details, it is showing Forbidden error. I tried with small one or two lines of description, it is working fine...

Any Idea why it is happening like this? is it a problem with my hosting?

Comment: You will have to share more details.

Comment: Can you give more info on the error ? Maybe copy the error here.

Comment: In my project details text area i am adding project details which is a longtext in mysql. I can add the details in localhost. But in live server it is showing Forbidden. Details are not going to DB. but again small texts are working fine.

Comment: 403 Forbidden error. Showing you don't have the permission for xyzconnect.php file.

Answer (score 1):

**Forbidden error.** mainly show if you have no permission to do this . Also may you face problem for your data type . You can change your data type longtext to `VARCHAR(255)`. Then i think you will not face those problem. Also check you permission .... to do like those type of action..

Comment: It is showing: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /xyz/editconnect.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You can set those file and folder permission as `777`

Comment: In my case my other files' permission is 0755... I made this one 777 & 0777 (just for a chance) , it started showing INTERNAL SERVER ERROR...